# Problem at create a new target in qtcreator

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, qt-creator

At create the first project and create the target, give me the next error:

[image: Error in IDE]

Console:

```
ricardo@zeus:~$ ubuntu-sdk
file:///usr/ubuntu-sdk-ide/lib/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ToolBar.qml:143:9: QML Item: Binding loop detected for property "layoutHeight"
file:///usr/ubuntu-sdk-ide/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/qml/DevicesPage/DevicePage.qml:170:13: QML ToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/ubuntu-sdk-ide/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/qml/DevicesPage/DevicePage.qml:170:13: QML ToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/ubuntu-sdk-ide/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/qml/DevicesPage/DevicePage.qml:170:13: QML ToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "width"
qml: Page_QMLTYPE_230(0x28bd490)"Ubuntu Publish": In Ubuntu.Components 1.3, the use of Page.title, Page.flickable and Page.head is deprecated. Use Page.header and the PageHeader component instead.
"The command \"/qmake\" could not be started."
file:///usr/ubuntu-sdk-ide/lib/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ToolBar.qml:143:9: QML Item: Binding loop detected for property "layoutHeight"
file:///usr/ubuntu-sdk-ide/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/qml/DevicesPage/DevicePage.qml:238:25: QML ToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/ubuntu-sdk-ide/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/qml/DevicesPage/DevicePage.qml:238:25: QML ToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
Could not get the architecture from:  "server didn't ACK"  defaulting to armhf
Could not get the architecture from:  "failed to start daemon *"  defaulting to armhf
QTextCursor::setPosition: Position '203' out of range
Filter is  "^(.*)-(.*)-amd64-(dev|ota[0-9]+)$"
Filter is  "^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(dev|ota[0-9]+)$"
Filter is  "^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(dev|ota[0-9]+)$"
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/bin/env' as the super user
Authenticating as: ricardo,,, (ricardo)
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
```

Logically I enter the password ricardo is the user who has permissions to use sudo . I have also tried entering the root password, but does not work either.

```
ricardo@zeus:/etc⟫ sudo cat sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

ricardo@zeus:/etc⟫ cat group | grep sudo
sudo:x:27:ricardo
```